# Using python models in django

Tags: django-models

I am new in django. This is my [django model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDjP2.png). But when I use the `Book.objects.all()` command in python shell, I am getting an error.

Why?? Please help.

Comment: the code is in the image shown above

Comment: What error are you getting? Please post code as text, not an image!

Comment: Please paste the code, not an image.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Prashant. Please read - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask especially Help others reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

This answer is very late however it may prove useful to anyone that views this question.

The error you will be experiencing is:

> TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, datetime.date found

This is because in your model you have the code:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title + self.publication_date
```

The error originates from the attempt to add a datetime object `self.publication_date`, to a string `self.title`. To fix this you can change your code to cast `self.publication_date` to a string like so:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title + str(self.publication_date)
```

To help with this further, I would suggest formatting the string representation of the `Book` object a little better to make it more readable.

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return '{} - {}'.format(self.title, str(self.publication_date))
```

The output from this would look something like this:

```
>>> from test.models import Book
>>> Book.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Book: MyBook - 2018-03-19>]>
```